# How to find out which pipes are facing wrong direction

Tags: pandas, shapefile, geopandas

I am trying to calculate the district heating system. I get the info from shapefiles – for pipes I have a geometry of linestrings with start and end coordinates. I created a geopandas dataframe:

```
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       |                                                                                                                      |
| ID    | geometry                                                                                                             |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       |                                                                                                                      |
| 0     | LINESTRING (1679896.423 5802688.586,   1679896.034 5802688.745)                                                      |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       |                                                                                                                      |
| 1     | LINESTRING (1679896.034 5802688.745, 1679892.419 5802689.660)                                                        |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       |                                                                                                                      |
| 2     | LINESTRING (1679908.185 5802692.533, 1679911.830 5802691.936,   1679927.258 5802689.562, 1679945.682 5802686.042)    |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       |                                                                                                                      |
| 3     | LINESTRING (1679945.667 5802685.478, 1679945.653 5802685.247)                                                        |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       |                                                                                                                      |
| 4     | ….                                                                                                                   |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

For calculations, I have to determine all the connections between the lines (current pipe has to have defined pipe previous and pipe next). I did it in a way where I created a starting point and ending point of a linestring, and merged dataframe with itself (paired ending points with starting points). Problem is, some of the linestrings (about 1/5 of all) are facing the wrong direction, so I simply get NaN results for them (because now ending point of current pipe doesn’t touch starting point of next, but simply another ending point).

```
+-------+-------------+-----------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       |             |                 |                                    |                                    |                                                                    |
| ID    | PipeNext    | PipePrevious    | StartPoint                         | EndPoint                           | Geometry                                                           |
+-------+-------------+-----------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       |             |                 |                                    |                                    |                                                                    |
| 1     | 2           | 477             | POINT (1679896.423 5802688.586)    | POINT (1679896.034 5802688.745)    | LINESTRING (1679896.423 5802688.586,   1679896.034 5802688.745)    |
|       |             |                 |                                    |                                    |                                                                    |
|       |             |                 |                                    |                                    |                                                                    |
+-------+-------------+-----------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       |             |                 |                                    |                                    |                                                                    |
| 7     | 8           | 477             | POINT (1679896.423 5802688.586)    | POINT (1679898.491 5802694.799)    | LINESTRING (1679896.423 5802688.586, 1679898.491 5802694.799)      |
|       |             |                 |                                    |                                    |                                                                    |
|       |             |                 |                                    |                                    |                                                                    |
+-------+-------------+-----------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       |             |                 |                                    |                                    |                                                                    |
| 3     | 467, 468    | Nan             | POINT (1679077.671 5802691.617)    | POINT (1679060.406 5802674.810)    | LINESTRING (1679077.671 5802691.617,   1679060.406 5802674.810)    |
|       |             |                 |                                    |                                    |                                                                    |
|       |             |                 |                                    |                                    |                                                                    |
+-------+-------------+-----------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Additional problem is, that there are examples where there are 10 pipes consecutively facing wrong direction (so between them, I actually get results, but they are wrong) – another problem is, that sometimes PipeNext is NaN simply because the current line is the end line.
Is there any way to be able to determine the pipes facing the wrong direction? If not, is it possible to make the direction of the lines visible on plot?

Edit - added current code:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import folium

import shapefile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
import contextily as ctx
df_pipes=gpd.read_file("DO_Hrastnik_odsek.shp")
df_user=gpd.read_file("DO_Hrastnik_objekt.shp")

df_pipes.crs = {'init': 'epsg:3912'}
df_pipes=df_pipes.to_crs("EPSG:3857")
df_user.crs = {'init': 'epsg:3912'}
df_user=df_user.to_crs("EPSG:3857")

df_pipes["ID"] = df_pipes.index + 1
df_pipes['ID']=df_pipes['ID'].astype(str)

df_pipes=df_pipes[["geometry","ID","LENGTH_3D"]].copy()

from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString

df_pipes["node_ups"] = gpd.GeoSeries([Point(list(pt['geometry'].coords)[0]) for i,pt in df_pipes.iterrows()])
df_pipes["node_dws"] = gpd.GeoSeries([Point(list(pt['geometry'].coords)[-1]) for i,pt in df_pipes.iterrows()])

tmp = df_pipes[['ID', 'node_dws', 'node_ups']]

df_connections=pd.merge(tmp, tmp, left_on='node_dws', right_on='node_ups',how="outer")
df_connections=pd.merge(df_connections, tmp, left_on='node_ups_x', right_on='node_dws',how="outer")

df_connections.drop(['node_dws_y', 'node_ups_y','node_dws', 'node_ups'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df_connections = df_connections[df_connections['ID_x'].notna()]

df_connections = df_connections.rename(columns={'ID_x': 'ID_pipe', 'node_dws_x': 'node_dws','node_ups_x': 'node_ups', 'ID_y': 'pipeNext','ID': 'pipePrevious'})

tmp = df_connections[['ID_pipe', 'pipeNext', 'pipePrevious']]
df_connections=pd.merge(tmp, df_pipes, left_on='ID_pipe', right_on='ID',how="outer")
```

Comment: Would it not be possible to test if one point of your line matches a startpoint or an endpoint? It's not that your pipes include slope or something, it's just line information, so treat it like that.

Comment: @MaartenVeerman the problem is that somewhere there are multiple consecutive lines facing wrong direction. Between them, we get neighbours where next and previous are switched (their direction is upstream).

Comment: Could you make a small drawing of this? To outline your problem.

Comment: @MaartenVeerman  - Here is the part of the system: https://imgur.com/a/ejbHPru. 
Yellow lines are the wrong-direction lines.  
I have thought about doing something like this: _if endopoint(currentID) meets (endpointNEXTID), swap values (endpointNEXTID-startpointNEXTID), break, restart loop_  
This would rotate line by line, but seems very complex given the branched structure.

Comment: Can you please show us your code? It makes it easier for us to help if we can see how you've arrived at the second DataFrame and what can be tweaked to correct it.

Comment: To figure out which directions are *correct* the straight forward way is doing a tree search through all the pipes starting from the first pipe. By first pipe I mean the pipe where all the water comes from. If you go through the pipes in a different order, everything gets more complicated as you may need several passes and you may end up with all your pipes going in the wrong direction.

Comment: @Joooeey I added the current code. I have thought about defining the starting pipe and then searching the next one until the end of the system, but wont the really branched structure (where sometimes braches start with pipes facing wrong direction) make the code quite complex (or even impossible)? I have too add, that ID's of the pipes are completely random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea from the comments to check where the endpoints meet is the way to go and it isn't as complex as you say. Start at the starting pipe of your network (where all the water comes from – I assume that's a single pipe) and work your way down the network with a recursive function:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString # You can delete your own code after this line.

# df.apply is faster than iterrows, so I rewrote the following two lines
df_pipes['node_ups'] = df_pipes.geometry.apply(lambda linestring: Point(list(linestring.coords)[0])
df_pipes['node_dws'] = df_pipes.geometry.apply(lambda linestring: Point(list(linestring.coords)[-1])

def check_downstream(pipe_id, pipes):
    """Set next and previous pipe ID for all downstream pipes"""

    endpoint = pipes.loc[pipe_id, 'node_dws']
    next_ids = list(pipes['node_ups' == endpoint]['ID'])
    reversed_ids = list(pipes[(pipes['node_dws'] == endpoint) & (pipes['ID'] != pipe_id)]['ID'])
    for rev_id in reversed_ids:
        pipes.loc[rev_id, 'node_ups'], pipes.loc[rev_id, 'node_dws'] = pipes.loc[rev_id, 'node_dws'], pipes.loc[rev_id, 'node_ups']
    next_ids = next_ids + reversed_ids
    for nxt_id in next_ids:
        pipes.loc[pipe_id, 'pipeNext'] = nxt_id
        pipes.loc[nxt_id, 'pipePrevious'] = pipe_id
        check_downstream(nxt_id, pipes) # This is the recursive function call.


df_connections = df_pipes.copy()
df_connections['pipePrevious'] = 'undetermined'
df_connections['pipeNext'] = 'undetermined'

first_id = 99 # or whatever it is
check_downstream(first_id, df_connections)
```

Note that this does not reverse the Linestrings themselves but you could do that too if you need to.